# Catching the Back key on Android with an Inputmultiplexer

Tags: android, libgdx, back

ive got another Question for you.

So im trying to get the user input working on an options menu. For this i got:
1. The Stage and
2. An extra Inputadapter

I need the extra Inputadapter to catch the BACK key on Android. So i have used an Inputmultiflexer, which allows me to use both inputprocessors.

```
    InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    multiplexer.addProcessor(this);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);

    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

And my method to check for the BACK button looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode){


    if(keycode == Input.Keys.ESCAPE || keycode == Input.Keys.BACK){
        new MenuScreen(game);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The problem: Its not working at all. It does not go back, when using the Back key on Android or the Escape key on Desktop. The only thing the Console is printing out when pressing the Button is :

> Load KCM of non-default device may incur unexpected result

To be honest, i have no idea what its means and Google didnt help me either with that.

So how do i get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when debugging, you should use something like :

```
System.out.println("back was pressed");
```

If you see that output in the console then you know input is working. If that works, the only problem I see with your code is that you may have created a new screen class, you never made it switch screens. I noticed you passed in the game object, so you should probably have something like this:

```
game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm thx it works now, didnt notice i made the mistake with not actually switching the screen.

Comment: Load KCM of non-default device may incur unexpected result is just a warning. Anyone know how to get rid of it?